# Access item in nested dictionary with list items and sub-dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, slice

I have a dictionary that contains a list of dictionaries, that again contain lists. The dictionary contains information on whether certain features exist (Boolean) in a room-type of a flat. I would like to extract the dictionary related to a single one of these rooms - e.g. 'bedroom'.

I have tried several slicing methods. I got the closest result to what I actually wanted to achieve using the following code:

```
json['data']['offerAggregate']['property_aggregate']['property']['floors'][0]['units']['type_code' == 'bedroom']
```

However, I was still given the dictionary related to 'kitchen' instead of 'bedroom' (I guess because it is the first list entry).

I could also slice with position indexes easily, but the position of the dictionaries in the list can be different for other appartments and I need a universal approach.

Here's the full schema at the point where I have failed to slice further:

```
{'units': [{'type_code': 'kitchen',
   'features': [{'Code': 'fridge', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'freezer', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'oven', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'stove', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'pots-pans', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'dishes-cutlery', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'microwave', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'washing-machine', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'balcony', 'Exists': False},
    {'Code': 'table', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'chairs', 'Exists': False},
    {'Code': 'dryer', 'Exists': False}],
   'subunits': None},
  {'type_code': 'bathroom',
   'features': [{'Code': 'bathtub', 'Exists': False},
    {'Code': 'shower', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'sink', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'toilet', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': False}],
   'subunits': None},
  {'type_code': 'living-room',
   'features': [{'Code': 'chairs', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'sofa', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'sofa-bed', 'Exists': False},
    {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'balcony', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'coffee-table', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'table', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'tv', 'Exists': True}],
   'subunits': None},
  {'type_code': 'bedroom',
   'features': [{'Code': 'wardrobe', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'chest-of-drawers', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'sofa', 'Exists': False},
    {'Code': 'sofa-bed', 'Exists': False},
    {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': True},
    {'Code': 'balcony', 'Exists': False}],
   'subunits': [{'id': 'd63d98a7-a5a6-47e9-8754-4b89750e22a5',
     'type_code': 'double-bed',
     'features': None}]}]}
```

So, generally I believe I do understand the pattern of my data. But all my trials of slicing correctly have failed.

Any suggestions on this would be highly appreciated!

All the best,
Hannah

Comment: Can you instead post the full pattern of your data (rather than posting the point where you failed to retrieve the data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the bedrooms in a list comprehension like:

```
bedrooms = [i for i in data['units'] if i['type_code'] == 'bedroom']
```

Then you can access the features with:

```
for bedroom in bedrooms:
    bedroom['features']
```

If you only have one bedroom, you could loop through the list until you match it:

```
for room in data['units']:
    if room['type_code'] == 'bedroom':
        # bedroom found
        room['type_code']['features']
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic involved in dict key lookups nor list index lookups. Assuming (for readability)  we first define

```
units = json['data']['offerAggregate']['property_aggregate']['property']['floors'][0]['units'])
```

Then this

```
something = units['type_code' == 'bedroom']
```

is interpreted as

```
index = 'type_code' == 'bedroom'
something = unit[index]
```

since the literal string 'type_code' doesn't compare equal to the literal string 'bedroom', this is equal to:

```
index = False
something = unit[index]
```

and since `False == 0`, the final result is

```
something = unit[0]
```

which is the first dict (typecode=>'kitchen').

`units` is a list of dicts, so you have to loop over it to find the first dict which 'typecode' key has 'bedroom' for value:

```
bedroom == None

for stuff in units:
    if stuff["typecode"] == "bedroom":
        bedroom = stuff
        break
```

You can of course make this a function (taking a 'units' list and a typecode).

Another solution if typecodes are garanteed to be unique is to build an index dict:

```
units_by_typecode = {item['typecode']: item for item in units}
bedroom = units_by_typecode["bedroom"]
```

or to use some third-part lib that knows how to do such lookups (not sure but Panda might have this)